# Rails, param is missing or value:vote is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a vote model which has a candidate_vote:integer which also has an association between a candidate. i tried creating a form and i get this error  param is missing or the value is empty: vote

this is the form

```html
<%= form_for @vote do |f| %>
  <table>   
    <tbody>
      <% Position.includes(:candidates).order(:name).each do |position| %>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5"><%= position.name %></th>
        </tr>
        <% position.candidates.each do |candidate| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= image_tag(candidate.image, :size => '50x50') if candidate.image.attached? %></td>
            <td><%= candidate.name %></td>
            <td><%= candidate.info %></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag :candidate_votes, checked_value: '1', unchecked_value: '0' %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and the controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @vote = Vote.new
        @candidates = Candidate.all
    end

    def create
        @vote = Vote.create(vote_params)

        if @vote.save
            redirect_to @vote
        else
            render :new
            
        end
    end

    private 

    def vote_params
        params.require(:vote).permit(:candidate_vote, :candidate_id)
    end


end
```

with its respective models

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :candidate
end
```

```
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
    
    belongs_to :position

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :votes

    has_one_attached :image

    validates :image, presence: true,  content_type: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'] 

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :info, presence: true
end
```

whats wrong please or what am i not doing right?

Comment: you requiring `:candidate_vote, :candidate_id` params to be sent, but in your template code where form is, there is no field for `candidate_id`. Did you forget it?

Comment: yes the candidate_id is actually thats bringing the candidate name and info.

Comment: can you please write here which params you get in create method?

Comment: def vote_params
  params.require(:vote).permit(:candidate_vote, :candidate_id)
 end

Answer (score 0):

In your controller inside the create method change: `@vote = Vote.create(vote_params)` to  `@vote = Vote.new(vote_params)`

The rest is all looking good.

Comment: What params are you receiving?(You can see in the terminal what parameters are being send)

Answer (score 0):

I hate ERB, have some nice HAML:

```
= form_for @vote do |f|
  %table
    %tbody
      - Position.includes(:candidates).order(:name).each do |position|
        %tr
          %th{colspan: 5}= position.name
      - position.candidates.each do |candidate|
        %tr
          %td= image_tag(candidate.image, :size => '50x50') if candidate.image.attached?
          %td= candidate.name
          %td= candidate.info
          %td= check_box_tag "vote[candidate_votes[#{candidate.id}]]", checked_value: '1', unchecked_value: '0'
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

as zhisme says, you aren't passing the id of the candidate through the form.

I'm assuming that you want the person to be able to vote for more than one candidate?  if you don't, it might be worthwhile looking at the "radio_button" object, and returning the candidate as the value. e.g.:

```
= form_for @vote do |f|
  %table
    %tbody
      - Position.includes(:candidates).order(:name).each do |position|
        %tr
          %th{colspan: 5}= position.name
      - position.candidates.each do |candidate|
        %tr
          %td= image_tag(candidate.image, :size => '50x50') if candidate.image.attached?
          %td= candidate.name
          %td= candidate.info
          %td= f.radio_button :candidate_votes, candidate.id
  = f.submit "Submit"
```